# preg_replace http with https

Tags: php, preg-replace

Put simply, I need to check if the string in the variable $url is a simple http, if so, replace it with https - but I can't get it to work - any ideas:

```
$url="http://www.google.com"; // example http url ##
$url_replaced = preg_replace( '#^http://#','https://', $url ); // replace http with https ##
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not `str_replace` ?

```
$url="http://www.google.com"; // example http url ##
$url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url ); 
echo $url;
```

Comment: you both answered at the same time.. so Karo get's the points as he / she has less..

Comment: Just be careful the URL doesn't contain a query param with another url in it. For example:

`echo str_replace('http://', 'https://', 'http://foo.com?redirect=http://bar.com');  // https://foo.com?redirect=https://bar.com`

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace()` is unnecessary here. Just use `str_replace()`.

```
str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT use `str_replace`, as it can happen you will replace string in the middle (if the url is not encoded correctly).

`preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $url)`

Note the `/i` parameter for case insensitive and `^` saying it have to start with this string.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c3882b4640dad9b6988881c420246193194e37e

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a simple function that returns the link as secure. Much easier if you need to change a lot of links.

```
function secureLink($url){

$url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url ); 
return $url;
};
```